# Find image by Filename in Wikimedia Commons

Tags: json, api, wikipedia, wikimedia

When I call this API `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php` with following params:

```
"action": "query",
"format": "json",
"titles": "Albert Einstein",
"prop": "images"
```

I just get the title of the following images. For example the title: `File:Name-of-file.svg`

But how can I actually have the link of this file? To find the original size image in Wikimedia Commons. It begins with `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons` but then there is a URL folder with a different name for every image, then follows the image name. Is there an API for this?
Currently I'm using `https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Images`

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Just to need use *imageinfo&iiprop=url*

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=File:Albert_Einstein_Head.jpg&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url
```

Comment: Thank you from the bottoms of my heart ^^

Comment: Perfect. If using in JS in a browser, then `&origin=*` is also a must